# Which fields of the model in the django-haystack tutorial get indexed?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I'm trying to get my head around the [django-haystack tutorial](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) in order to add search functionality to my application. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand some key parts when it comes to build the search index.

In the tutorial, the following django model serves as an example:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
```

The respective index class for the `Note` model is this:

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Note
```

Last but not least, I'm asked to create a data template which looks like this:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.user.get_full_name }}
{{ object.body }}
```

After reading the whole tutorial, I'm still confused about what is getting indexed now. As far as I understand, the contents of the fields `author` and `pub_date` will be used to create the index. The field `text` is simply for providing some settings. And the data template specifies how the search results will be displayed later on, i.e., which fields of the model to use to be displayed in the search results.

Is this correct or am I completely wrong? The tutorial and the documentation are quite vague in a lot of aspects in my opinion. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Man, you typed exactly the exact question I came here to type, 2 years later!

Comment: Man, you typed exactly the exact question I came here to type, 4 years later! @GreenAsJade Man, you typed exactly the exact comment I came here to type, 2 years later! But I have something more to add. The documentation is actually total rubbish.

Answer (score 18):

You're right, the tutorial seems a little vague, but here's how I understand it. For each instance of the `Note` model, Haystack renders the data template using that instance and indexes the rendered templates. The rendered template is the "document" for the instance. The tutorial says, "This allows us to use a data template (rather than error prone concatenation) to build the document the search engine will use in searching." So if you only wanted the `title` field to be searchable, you would only include `{{ object.title }}` in the data template.

So the other fields in the `NoteIndex` model are used for filtering search query results. If your index model looked just like this:

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
  text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
```

you would not be able to issue a search query that says, "Give me all the Notes *published in the last year* where `foo` appears in the document text." If you include `pub_date` as a field in your `NoteIndex` (as they do in the tutorial) then you can make a query such as the following:

```
recent_results = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='foo').order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

which asks for the 5 most recently published documents that contain the word `foo`. I suppose that, without including `pub_date` in the `NoteIndex` model, you could query for `content='foo'` and then filter the results yourself, but I'd imagine it's a much more efficient query if you tell Haystack at indexing time about the fields you might want to filter on.

As for how the search results will be displayed, you use a different template to specify that. In the most basic Haystack usage, which they show in the tutorial, the template for displaying search results goes in search/search.html: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#search-template
You can iterate through the search results and print out whatever fields of the model instance (`result.object`) that you'd like.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Emily, you explained it very well. :) One essential point I didn't understand was that the `text` field is enough to do a full-text search and that the other fields are only used for further filtering the search results. The tutorial could have been written more clearly because I didn't get what the definition of *document* means in the context of searching. But now I think it's clear to me. Vielen Dank! :)

Answer (score 2):

In your class definition,

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')
```

Haystack stores the index of `user` attribute of database as `author` , and the index of the database field `pub_date` as `pub_date` in index

The template includes only the "searchable" fields. For example, you might want to save some sensitive data in the search indices you can hide it from the search by not specifying it in the template.

`text` can be thought of as free text search

Comment: Ah, I thought that the searchable fields would be defined already by specifying the fields that should be indexed. But the index sources can be different from the searchable fields. I think this is what I didn't understand. Thank you! :)